# div tag always visible in google chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I have a div that contains a radio button and should be always visible. It's working fine in Firefox but not in Google Chrome.
In Firefox if I scroll the page the div is visible and I can select the desired option. In Chrome the div lose its width and it's positioned at the end of the page. To select an option is necessary to scroll the page to bottom.

Thanks.

//CSS

```css
#filtru_contracte
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 3;    
}
```

```html
<div id="filtru_contracte" class="btn btn-success">
    <i class="fa fa-filter fa-2x"></i> Filtru contracte
    <div>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="ctr_filter" id="rb_in_lucru" value="1"> În lucru</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="ctr_filter" id="rb_finalizate" value="2"> Finalizate</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="ctr_filter" id="rb_toate" value="3"> Toate</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

//HTML

Comment: For me, it is positioned bottom and left on latest Chrome version. As expected. I assume you use bootstrap. I don't understand why you use `btn btn-success` classes on div.